# Eclipse not compatible with jdk1.4

Tags: eclipse

Hi Am using eclipse galileo and jdk version jdk1.4.Am not able to open eclipse as its give "jdk1.5 or above version required" error.How do i resolve it?

Comment: use higher versions of jdk like jdk1.6

Comment: To add to Jaguar's comment, use the higher version, but set the compatibility to 1.4 in your project

Comment: Amit,how do i do the that?to build my project i need jdk1.4 itself

Comment: Copy and paste the lastest version of JRE from your C:\program files\jre...
to the eclipse folder and rename it as "JRE" and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy and paste the lastest version of JRE from your `C:\program files\jre...` to the eclipse folder and rename it as "JRE" and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please install JDK/JRE version 1.5 or above, and then add the following to the eclipse.ini file in the eclipse home directory

-vm

$JDK_HOME\bin

Note: The path of the JRE should be in the line after -vm and not in the same line.

Eclipse will use the JVM available at this path to launch